# What would be the best way to memorize the 10 by 10 multiplication table?

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, mental-arithmetic, mnemonic

Hear me out before you start downvoting please. I have a learning disability so no matter how hard I try I can’t memorize the table. Please give some tips/hints on how to memorize the table. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think anyone can (or should)  give all purpose, one-size-fits-all, advice on a question like this.  Talk to someone who knows you...who knows your strengths and weaknesses.

Answer (score 1):

Without more context on why you're having difficulty, we can't specifically tailor an answer to you.

"Memorizing" the times table isn't the most fruitful endeavor, but instead you should try and memorize the patterns that pop up. For example, $$\begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\2 &  &  &  & 10 &  &  &  &  & \\ 3 &  &  &  & 15 &  &  &  &  & \\4 &  &  &  & 20 &  &  &  &  & \\5 & 10 & 15 & 20 & 25 & 30 & 35 & 40 & 45 & 50\\6 &  &  &  & 30 &  &  &  &  & \\7 &  &  &  & 35 &  &  &  &  & \\8 &  &  &  & 40 &  &  &  &  & \\9 &  &  &  & 45 &  &  &  &  & \\10 &  &  &  & 50 &  &  &  &  & \\\end{matrix}$$

For one, the table is symmetric, meaning you can cut down how much you need to memorize quite a bit. Take for example the times table written out for $5$. Notice how each number ends in either $5$ or $0$. If we look at the entries for multiplying by $10$, $$\begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 20\\ 3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 30\\4 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 40\\5 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 50\\6 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 60\\7 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 70\\8 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 80\\9 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 90\\10 & 20 & 30 & 40 & 50 & 60 & 70 & 80 & 90 & 100\\\end{matrix}$$ you basically take the numbers and add a zero. If we look at the times table for $2$: $$\begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10 & 12 & 14 & 16 & 18 & 20\\ 3 & 6 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\4 &  8&  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\5 & 10 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\6 & 12 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\7 & 14 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\8 & 16 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\9 & 18 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\10 & 20 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\\end{matrix}$$ each product ends in $0$, $2$, $4$, $6$, or $8$.

Personally, if I'm asked to fill out the times table, these are the kinds of patterns I employ. However, again without more information on *what* you're struggling with, tailoring an answer is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to learn, say,  a poem by heart?  In that case treat the table like a poem.  Do NOT learn the pattern $3, 6, 9,\dots$ but "One times three equal three; two times three equals six, three times three equals nine ..." and so on.  You'll finally get it.

Good luck!